# How to see JetpackCompose kotlin source in Android Studio (4.2)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-studio-4.2

When I `command-click` into the JetpackCompose function, all I see is below (as per Android Studio 4.2)

[image]

I click `Download Sources`, but nothing happens. I click `Decompile to Java`, it's relative cryptic code to understand the Java version of it. How could I see the source easily in Android Studio?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169575797

Comment: I had the same issue with Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3 and adding `androidx.compose.compiler` to the dependencies solved this issue