# What's the different between aspectRatio(1f) and fillMaxSize() for JetpackCompose Modifier attribute

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I set the modifier as below

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Clock(modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

I have both `fillMaxSize()` and `aspectRaio(1f)` as per I see other people code and have both set. Are they doing the same thing? Or they are needed for different purposes? (I tried removing one of each, and seems to result the same).

P/S: I tried to view the code to understand the different but can't as per [How to see JetpackCompose kotlin source in Android Studio (4.2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64312881/how-to-see-jetpackcompose-kotlin-source-in-android-studio-4-2)

Answer (score 13):

Looks like `aspectRatio(1f)` will make it square, while `fillMaxSize()` will make it take up the entire screen.

An example below of either

```
        setContent {
            Clock(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .aspectRatio(1.0f)
                .padding(64.dp))
        }
```

or

```
        setContent {
            Clock(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(64.dp))
        }
```

where the `fillMaxSize()` takes precedence, the `drawRect` will be as below

[image]

But when we have `aspectRation(1.0f)`, with an example either of the below,

```
        setContent {
            Clock(modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1.0f)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(64.dp))
        }
```

or

```
        setContent {
            Clock(modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1.0f)
                .padding(64.dp))
        }
```

it shall be

[image]